# Tomcat compiles JSP and inconsistently Creates a Helper Class

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I've run into a strange problem and I can't find anything about it on the forums. I was hoping maybe someone else has seen it and can give me some insight.

I'm running tomcat 6.0 under Windows. Our application uses the Archibus facilities management system. For UI screens Archibus uses it's own custom XML schema and the user interface code is referred to as View files. At run time Archibus converts these View files to jsp and then Tomcat converts the jsp to java, and then class, files.

I am running into a situation where Tomcat does not convert the jsp files to java files in a consistent way. Normally (when everything works ok) Tomcat converts selfCertWelcome.jsp to 3 files : selfCertMain_jsp.java, selfCertMain_jsp.class & selfCertMain_jsp$helper.class.

About every 20th time or so Tomcat converts the jsp in a different way. Instead of 3 files it creates 2 files selfCertMain_jsp.java & selfCertMain_jsp.class. When this happens it appears that the selfCertMain_jsp.class inlines the code that normally is put into the selfCertMain_jsp$helper.class. Unfortunately when the code is inlined it does not load correctly. No error message is produced but the screen comes up blank (nothing displayed).

In production the app server is restarted every night and the schemaCompiled folder is deleted. What this means is that the jsp files get recreated on a daily basis. Sometimes when they get created this problem occurs and the only way to correct it is to delete the jsp file and let Tomcat recompile it hoping that it re compiles it correctly.

I verified the jsp files created by Archibus are identical when the problem occurs and when it does not. Therefore I feel pretty certain the issue lies with Tomcat.

Has anyone seen something like this before? Any suggestions on how I might go about resolving this?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Are you using the Sun/Oracle JDK?

Comment: Probably not the best idea to be defining classes in JSP anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JDK1.6.0_23.

Comment: I am not defining classes in the JSP, the JSP is converted into class files by Tomcat